# Force chrome to do use merge sort or quick sort for array#sort

Tags: algorithm, google-chrome, sorting

As pointed out [here](http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/14-Sorting-Were-Doing-It-Wrong.html), chrome's default sort is unstable for arrays > 22 elements. Is there a way to force chrome to use a stable sort algorithm?

Comment: I don't think you can choose the sorting algorithm. It was never guaranteed to be stable in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Stable sort in Array#sort? No, you can't specify algorithm to use (and standard doesn't say anything about it). So you can either write your own `sort` function or extend the key:

> Unstable sorting algorithms can be specially implemented to be stable. One way of doing this is to artificially extend the key comparison, so that comparisons between two objects with otherwise equal keys are decided using the order of the entries in the original data order as a tie-breaker